# How to add two filters in different level to the same GlazedList table?

Tags: java, swing, filter, glazedlists

I have created a table which i want to filter it in two different level.
first filter it with radio button on the file extension like(.jpg, .doc, the rest).
Second filter it with textField to search something inside the first filtered.
As below you can see in demo i can filter the table with radio button but i don't know how to apply the second level filter (JTextField) on the table.

**Does any body know how to do it?**

[image]

```
public class TwoLevelFilterTablePanel extends OeVubPanel {
private static final File DirectoryEngine = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures");
private JRadioButton jpg,doc,others;
private ButtonGroup radioSet;
private JTextField txtFilter;
private JTable glazedTable;
private BasicEventList<MyCode> eventList;
private JPanel filterPanel,radioSetPanel;

public TwoLevelFilterTablePanel(BasicEventList<MyCode> eventList) {
    this.eventList=eventList;
    createComponents();
    layoutComponents();
}

public void createComponents() {
    jpg = new JRadioButton("jpg");
    doc= new JRadioButton("doc");
    others= new JRadioButton("other");
    radioSet = new ButtonGroup();
    radioSet.add(jpg);
    radioSet.add(doc);
    radioSet.add(others);
    txtFilter = new JTextField();

    radioSetPanel = new JPanel();
    radioSetPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(radioSetPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    radioSetPanel.add(jpg);
    radioSetPanel.add(doc);
    radioSetPanel.add(others);
    filterPanel=new JPanel();
    filterPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(filterPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    filterPanel.add(radioSetPanel);
    filterPanel.add(txtFilter);

    final BarcodeMatcherEditor barcodeMatcherEditor = new BarcodeMatcherEditor(jpg,doc,others);
    final FilterList filteredRadioSet = new FilterList(eventList, barcodeMatcherEditor);

    // build a JTable
    String[] propertyNames = new String[] {"name", "size","date"};
    String[] columnLabels = new String[] {"Name", "Size","Date"};
    TableFormat tf = GlazedLists.tableFormat(MyCode.class, propertyNames, columnLabels);
    glazedTable = new JTable(new EventTableModel(filteredRadioSet, tf));
}

public void layoutComponents() {
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(filterPanel);
    add(new WebScrollPane(glazedTable));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicEventList<MyCode> eventList  = new BasicEventList<MyCode>();
    for(File file : DirectoryEngine.listFiles()){
        eventList.add(new MyCode(file.getName(),file.length(),new Date(file.lastModified())));
    }
    TwoLevelFilterTablePanel demo = new TwoLevelFilterTablePanel(eventList );
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
    cp.add(demo);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocation(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

MatcherEditor class:

```
public class BarcodeMatcherEditor extends AbstractMatcherEditor implements ActionListener {
    private JRadioButton jpg,doc,others;
    public BarcodeMatcherEditor(JRadioButton jpg, JRadioButton doc, JRadioButton others) {
        this.jpg = jpg;
        this.doc=doc;
        this.others =others;
        this.jpg.addActionListener(this);
        this.doc.addActionListener(this);
        this.others.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        final String filter = ((JRadioButton)e.getSource()).getText();
        if (filter == null)
            this.fireMatchAll();
        else
            this.fireChanged(new BarcodeFilterMatcher(filter));
    }

    private static class BarcodeFilterMatcher implements Matcher {
        private final String filter;
        public BarcodeFilterMatcher(String filter) {
            this.filter = filter;
        }
        public boolean matches(Object item) {
            final MyCode code = (MyCode) item;
            return return filter.equals("other") || code.getName().endsWith(this.filter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply chain two `FilterList`s together:

```
EventList<Person> personLists = ...
...
FilterList<Person> filterListByGender = new FilterList<Person>(personList, genderMatchEditor);
FilterList<Person> filterListBySurname = new FilterList<Person>(filterByGender, textSurnameMatchEditor);
// Continue using the filterListBySurname as you usually would
...
```